# who tread whit 360 video in ios device (via react ts and vimeo)

Tags: ios, reactjs, vimeo, 360-virtual-reality

I am working on 360 videos in a React App where I share my Vimeo videos directly via Viemo embedded player.

I ran some test cases(see below) and I got few problems. I have been searching solution for a week but I could not find anything critical.

Who has experience of processing with 360 video in IOS devices? The solution suggests a third party is acceptable.

[image]